# How Does Duplicating Files To Reduce Read Time On Disks Work?

Tags: hard-drive, filesystems, dvd, duplicate, cd

i recently looked into game files of a Sega Dreamcast game called "Tokyo Bus Guide", and i found a odd thing, there were tons of duplicate files!

when i researched on it and an [Quora Comment Said](https://qr.ae/prQBkL) it was a technique used back in the days to reduce load times as the disk reader head can read the copy of that file near it...

i wanted to know how does this actually work? and how does the disk reader know about a duplicate file near it?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The quora answer already explained it. What didn't you understand?

On something as slow as a DVD, seek time was a *biggie*. It could take half a second to traverse inner to outer edge. HDD already made that less beneficial, SSD makes it pointless.

The reader has no clue there's another copy of the file somewhere else; it just fetches the one it's told to fetch, which the programmer ensures is physically nearby.

Comment: so basically you're saying reader works normally, it's upto the software manage & to tell it to fetch the file near it

Comment: …the same as any read operation. It only reads what it's told to read.